# Unity - How can i just rotate the pivot, not the Object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

no more explanation needed i think. I just want to rotate the pivot of my object but not the object itself. i want to object stays in position ... 
I watched a movie in YouTube but it couldn't helped. i want to rotate to pivot of a canvas object. I couldn't found answer any were else.

Comment: No.. you need to explan your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can not change the pivot of a model/object in Unity, you can use external software to manipulate the pivot of the model (3dsMax, Blender, Maya, etc...)

Comment: @zwcloud I don't know what more i can explain!! what do you want me that i explain?! ( do you unity? ) my explanation is clear i think.

Comment: I can understand moving the pivot of a object. But what is rotate the pivot? Rotate what around what?

Comment: @Hristo: Yeah you're right. but it's a Canvas. i can't send or edit it in an external software... .

Comment: Well why don't you then just add an empty `GameObject` and make it the parent of the `Canvas`, then you could position the empty object as it were a pivot.

Comment: I still can't understand *rotating the pivot*...

Comment: @Hristo: I previously did it this way as you say ... but I want to know is there another way to do this. ...

Comment: *solved it by putting canvas as a child of an Empty Object and moving it instead*, Yes! That's it. I think you have solved your problem properly and there should be no better way. It's a common usage of an empty GameObject.

Comment: So than you zwcloud & Hristo. that's i worried about( that maybe my solution be a poor solution) . thanks so much. :)